# magento setup:static-content:deploy issue

Tags: magento2

Complete noob here, I've installed magento locally to learn more about it, and try to build an ecommerce site. I've succesfully installed it with xampp and composer, however I get no images displayed, and when attempting to click on menu items it does nothing. Everywhere says run this command:

> bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

So I put this at the end of the url of `localhost/magento2`. So it's `localhost/magento2bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and hit go. I get a 403 code Access forbidden

Is there somewhere I should be running this command specifically? How do I do that? Or how do I fix the 403 error? I've done some searching, but can't seem to find the answer to my problem

Comment: Run that commamd in console at your magento root directory instead of URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everywhere says run this command: bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

As you said, people say run that **command**: `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

So if you are using Linux/UNIX OS-based, then open your Terminal or alternative application which always packed inside your OS. Then type

```
cd /absolute/path/to/your/magento/folder
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

If you are using Windows, then make sure you added PHP executable file to your Environment Path, after that open up your Windows Command Prompt (cmd) and:

```
cd /absolute/path/to/your/magento/folder
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Finally, remember that **Google** is your friend.

Comment: I think all I needed to do was have php before the command line when I did it in CMD. I had been just entering in the command with out php. I had been googling for hours trying to figure this out lol. And of course it was this simple.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command in command line.